# How can I do a mutable borrow after an immutable borrow?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

The code

```
fn play(&self, game: &mut crate::game::Game) {
    let player_in_turn: &Player = game.get_player_in_turn();
    match player_in_turn.player_kind {
        PlayerKind::AI => {
            player_in_turn.do_random_move(&mut game);
        }
        _ => {
            panic!("not implemented yet");
        }
    }
    game.status = Status::ExitGame;
}
```

Where `get_player_in_turn` is

```
pub fn get_player_in_turn(&self) -> &Player {
    match self.status {
        Status::InGame(ig_status) => match ig_status {
            InGameStatus::PlayFirst => {
                if self.player_a.play_order == PlayOrder::First {
                    &self.player_a
                } else {
                    &self.player_b
                }
            }
            InGameStatus::PlaySecond => {
                if self.player_a.play_order == PlayOrder::Second {
                    &self.player_a
                } else {
                    &self.player_b
                }
            }
        },
        _ => {
            panic!("get_player_in_turn called when not in a in-game status");
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler is telling me

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `game` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src\game\status\in_game_status.rs:28:47
   |
25 |         let player_in_turn: &Player = game.get_player_in_turn();
   |                                       ------------------------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
28 |                 player_in_turn.do_random_move(&mut game);
   |                                -------------- ^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
   |                                |
   |                                immutable borrow later used by call
```

Usually I am able to understand the what and the why of compilers erros

### I understand this

1. `let player_in_turn: &Player = game.get_player_in_turn();`  : I keep from `game` a ref to the current player; so I get an immutable ref of kind &Player

   Here the `game` variable is immutably borrowed because of fn signature `get_player_in_turn(&self)`. That's right, I do not want allow modifications to game in the get_player_in_turn, but also I need a ref because I need the player in turn, not a copy, or what else
2. `player_in_turn.do_random_move(&mut game);` : The instance of Player now alters the game itself doing its move

   And here `game` should be passed as mutable because it's the goal of `do_random_move`

### Question

I can understand the *why* of this but not how can I workaround

Comment: What in `do_random_move()`? Can you take only parts of `game`?

Comment: It might be better to return something like a `PlayerId` that thinly wraps the index in an array/key in a hashmap/whatever you use to keep track of your players and is cheaply copyable and then make `do_random_move` a method on `Game` that takes that `PlayerId` rather than the other way around.

Comment: I was going to have a play, but no working code. If you provide some small working code that exhibits the problem, it would be more useful.

Comment: Your panic suggests that a player that is in the game, may not be in the game. Have you considered having the player not be part of the game (they play the game, but are not part of it).

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Please share a minimal reproductible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, you know why this happens. Optimal workaround is to rewrite your code to use less borrowing. So you definitely can't do that if you want to modify some previously borrowed data. But if your `do_random_move()` function does not change internals of `Player`s, then you can use [this design pattern](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/idioms/temporary-mutability.html).

The core idea is to split borrowing into parts. Right now you are borrowing full `Game` structure when calling `get_player_in_turn`, but you only need 3 fields there: `status, player_a, player_b`. You can create a new function that takes them as arguments and this will split your borrowing and will allow you to borrow other fields of `Game` later (probably for `do_random_move` implementation).

[here is example code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1a52dfbb9443c3e4829211df9288b716)